# In Python, how to convert array of bits to array of bytes?

Tags: python, bitmap, arrays, python-imaging-library

Python PIL library has `Image.getdata()` method, which return raw image data, writing:

```
list(im.convert("1").getdata())
```

will return an array of bits. Each bit corresponds to one image pixel - pixel can only be black or white because of "1" mode.

I would like to have an array which size is 8 times smaller. Each array element contains one byte.

My questions are:

- **1. Can I get such an array of bytes directly from PIL?**
- **2. If not, how to convert array of bits returned by PIL to smaller array of bytes?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a thing about PIL and I haven't used Python for some time, but here is my take at this bits to bytes conversion problem.

```
import itertools
# assuming that `bits` is your array of bits (0 or 1)
# ordered from LSB to MSB in consecutive bytes they represent
# e.g. bits = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] will give you bytes = [128,255]
bytes = [sum([byte[b] << b for b in range(0,8)])
            for byte in zip(*(iter(bits),) * 8)
        ]
# warning! if len(bits) % 8 != 0, then these last bits will be lost
```

This code should be mostly self-explanatory.

Comment: In case of bits array that uses values different than 0 and 1, fix `byte[b]` accordingly, e.g. use `[0,1][byte[b]>0]` instead.

Comment: This is what you get, when you become dormant language user... The whole `zip(*[itertools.islice(bits, i, None, 8) for i in range(0,8)])` can be obviously simplified into `zip(*(iter(bits),) * 8)`. I'll fix it in the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

PIL's `ImagingCore` can easily be converted to bytes:

```
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open("python.jpg", "r")
data = img.convert("1").getdata()
bytes = bytearray(data)
```

This gives you a `bytearray()` list of bytes which can then be manipulated or written to a file. You could write this to a file by doing:

```
with open("filename", "w") as f:
    f.write(b"".join(map(bytes, data)))
```

I hope this helps!

It's probably worth noting too that Python in fact does not
have a data type for **bits**. And that `list(data)` returns
a list of `int`(s) and not "bits" as you *thought*?

Example:

```
>>> list(data)[:10]
[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
>>> set(list(data))
set([0, 255])
>>> set(map(type, list(data)))
set([<type 'int'>])
```

So in reality you are not saving any data by doing this.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html for Python data types and operations. You **can** perform "bit" operations, but there is no "bit" data type.

Comment: No it doesn't help at all. You just didn't understand the question. Note: len(list(img.convert("1").getdata())) == len(bytearray(img.convert("1").getdata()))

Comment: I beg your pardon? That expression evaluates to True. What exactly is your point?

Comment: Exactly - that expression evaluates to True. That's the problem. I want to get an array such as len(theArray) = len(bytearray(img.convert("1").getdata())) / 8. I want an array of bytes - what getdata gives me is an array of bits. They can be packed.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not see that. You get an array (*more precisely: a list of ints*) not "bits".

Comment: A list of int(s) is not an array of "bits".

Comment: You are right that this is a list of ints. But also the truth is that those ints are only 0's and 1's. So effectively they are bits. Storing 0's and 1's as ints are not effective and that's why I looking for a way to pack it to an array where each element will be in range 0-255 not 0-1.

Comment: I'm sorry if you look carefully, it **is not** a list of 0's and 1's but a list of 0's and 255's.

Comment: OK, still this is array of TWO values. It can be O and 1, 0 and 255 or cat and dog is doesn't matter. Effectively these are bits and they can be packed to BYTES.